# replace a clip with a different size clip but keep the scale in Premiere CC

Tags: premiere, scale

I have edited a 640 x 360 clip into a sequence in Premiere CC. The sequence includes changes to the scale for different shots. Now I want to replace the 640 x 360 clip with a 1920 x 1080 version of the same clip. When I do that, the apparent scale increases by a factor of 3; a shot in the sequence that should have a scale of 100% now APPEARS to be at 300%.

[image]

I'm sure it's because the new clip is so much bigger.  But is there a workaround that lets me keep the APPARENT zoom level of the original, tiny clip?  That is, can I make this new clip LOOK like its scale is 100% when the original sequence had the scale set to 100%? Can they look the same?

BTW, I know I can set the scale of each shot manually in the timeline.  But I may have 50 or more edits so I'm looking for a global solution.  I was hoping there was like a "master scale" setting for clips in the media browser, but I didn't find one.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow 100%, but you could put your sequence into a new sequence (nesting) and apply scale to that?

Comment: If that's an option, that might be the perfect solution! You should add this as an Answer. If it works out, I'll give you a up-vote (and possibly mark it as The Answer, though I want to try AJ Henderson's answer below too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the fact, no I don't.  If you know before the fact in the future though, you can put the source on a timeline by itself and apply the scale there and make all the clips point at that timeline.  This is the same technique I use in After Effects whenever I am working with animating a base layer that I know I am going to need to change.  That way I can make a simple change to the source clip and not have it impact the overall sequence.

Comment: Thanks AJ! I'll experiment with this tomorrow night when I have free time.

Comment: I did some experimenting and it looks like this might be a winner. At the moment the exported video only has 640x360 resolution even though I'm using the 1920x1080 clip. I'm modifying my workflow to avoid that problem: the empty sequence needs to be 1920x1080, and when I put in the raw footage that's 640x360 I'll just increase its scale to 300%. Later, I can replace that tiny file with the big 1920x1080 file and the whole sequence will stay 1920x1080. If this works I'll come here and mark your answer as The Answer.

Comment: There are several more steps in my workflow, but your suggestion formed the foundation of the solution so I marked it as The Answer.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer if you want to include whatever was missing.

Comment: There's nothing missing conceptually. I just made a big, elaborate workflow because I've hired an editor and I want it to be foolproof for him. The whole reason I'm doing this is so I can email him tiny files instead of 2 GB files.  He'll edit them, return the Premiere file to me, and I'll replace the tiny files in it with the 1920x1080 source files. That way I benefit from his editing but I still get HD quality output (and I can send the initial raw footage to him quickly instead of waiting for it overnight to upload).

Answer (score 1):

Premiere CC lets you adjust the dimensions of the sequence.  It will keep the same scale changes (zoom in & out) in the timeline.  So increase the dimensions of the sequence to accommodate the larger clip, then replace the small clip with the large clip.

This isn't a perfect solution. For example, titles will appear very small, and will not be in the right positions, relative to the new larger clip. I'm pretty sure that any position changes of the clip will be reduced as well, since they're in pixels rather than percentages of the width/height of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing this with an entire project. You'll need to go into each individual nest or sequence, resize the sequence, and then replace the clips.